# Section 5.4 Rails Tutorial

Tags: railstutorial.org

I'm tearing my hair out. I'm doing the Rails Tutorial by Hartl, and everything has been working until section 5.4.

It seems to be that I generated a new controller, then generated the integration_test user_pages, then the whole thing went haywire. I can't for the life of me work out what I've done wrong or where to start. I even tried destroying both and the same error comes out. Please help!

### My Code

```
Jordan-Poulton:Projects academy$ cd first_app/
Jordan-Poulton:first_app academy$ subl .
Jordan-Poulton:first_app academy$ rails generate controller Users new --no-test-framework
/Users/academy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:197: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr in PATH, mode 040777
/Users/academy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:197: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr in PATH, mode 040777
      create  app/controllers/users_controller.rb
       route  get "users/new"
      invoke  erb
      create    app/views/users
      create    app/views/users/new.html.erb
      invoke  helper
      create    app/helpers/users_helper.rb
      invoke  assets
      invoke    coffee
   identical      app/assets/javascripts/users.js.coffee
      invoke    scss
      create      app/assets/stylesheets/users.css.scss
Jordan-Poulton:first_app academy$ rails generate integration_test user_pages
/Users/academy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:197: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr in PATH, mode 040777
/Users/academy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:197: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr in PATH, mode 040777
      invoke  rspec
      create    spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb
Jordan-Poulton:first_app academy$ rails s
/Users/academy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:197: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr in PATH, mode 040777
/Users/academy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:197: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr in PATH, mode 040777
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.12 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Users/academy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:185:in `default_controller_and_action': missing :action (ArgumentError)
    from /Users/academy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:78:in `normalize_options!'
    from /Users/academy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:61:in `initialize'
    from /Users/academy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1304:in `new'
    from /Users/academy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1304:in `add_route'
    from /Users/academy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1284:in `decomposed_match'
    from /Users/academy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1270:in `block in match'
    from /Users/academy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1270:in `each'
    from /Users/academy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1270:in `match'
    from /Users/academy/Projects/first_app/config/routes.rb:6:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/academy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:282:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/academy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:282:in `eval_block'
    from /Users/academy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:260:in `draw'
    from /Users/academy/Projects/first_app/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/academy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
    from /Users/academy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
    from /Users/academy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/academy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
    from /Users/academy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
    from /Users/academy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
    from /Users/academy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
    from /Users/academy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
    from /Users/academy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
    from /Users/academy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:78:in `call'
    from /Users/academy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:78:in `execute'
    from /Users/academy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
    from /Users/academy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
    from /Users/academy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:66:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /Users/academy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/academy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/academy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/academy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /Users/academy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/academy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/academy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/academy/Projects/first_app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/academy/Projects/first_app/config.ru:3:in `require'
    from /Users/academy/Projects/first_app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/academy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/academy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /Users/academy/Projects/first_app/config.ru:in `new'
    from /Users/academy/Projects/first_app/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /Users/academy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
    from /Users/academy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/academy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
    from /Users/academy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
    from /Users/academy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/academy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
    from /Users/academy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
    from /Users/academy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/academy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /Users/academy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your controller. Content should be this

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end
end
```

and your routes.rb

```
#config/routes.rb
FirstApp::Application.routes.draw do

get "users/new"

root to: 'pages#home'
```

Run the following commands before rails s, just in case:

```
bundle install
bundle update
rake db:migrate
```

Sometimes a rake db:reset could help, but this will destroy and rebuild your database in your development environment.